# How can I clean up a variables in HTML and reuse it?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing an HTML page that can be a calculator in a web page.

I need to design M+,MR,MC function for it, same as a calculator

- M+ is for store the answer in the memory
- MR is load the memory
- MC is clean the memory

But I found that after I clean the memory, I can't get the new memory again

```
function M(){
   M = document.forms[0].elements[2].value
}

function MR(){
   document.forms[0].elements[0].value = M
}

function MC(){
   M = 0
}
```

Comment: You have a conflict of naming – `M` can't refer to both the memory value and `function M`. You'll want to rename one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call the function to store in memory the same as the variable to hold the value. Your `function M` overwrites its own definition with the value of the first value stored.

Hint: don't use undeclared variables.

Answer (score 0):

This one should be almost the same.

to delete or reset object use: `delete obj`

[Javascript DELETE Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

```
function M(){
   return document.forms[0].elements[2].value
}
function MR(){
   document.forms[0].elements[0].value = M()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use reset()

example

document.getElementById("myForm").reset();